# Strange web traffic issues with Apple servers from Dubai

Tags: networking, macos

I know this is rather unorthodox for SU but this thing has been really puzzling me...

For the last 3 days, all traffic from my home to Apple servers has been erratic at best, including :

- *access to iOS App Store from all iOS devices*: text loads OK, but no image loads and app downloads mostly hang in the middle (I say mostly because < 5% of them came to an end)
- *access to Mac App Store from mac devices*: sometimes nothing comes up, at best only text loads, *but* here app downloads work OK
- *access to http://www.apple.com*: works 80% of the time but on some pages images don't load or take forever to load
- *ping www.apple.com (on c. 2000 packets transmitted)*: 1.5% packet loss and avg round-trip time c. 110ms

Now for the control tests:

- access to all the above works perfectly from another connection (my workplace's wifi or my iPhone on cellular data)
- access to the rest of the web works fine from my home connection
- ping on other websites (google.com and stackoverflow.com): c. 1.1% packet loss and avg round-trip time c. 14ms (resp. 230ms)

So for me it's either :

- some nasty "stuff" going on between my home and (only) Apple's servers; then, I wonder, what could that be?
- my home connexion (fiver) is going crap but it only shows on Apple apps/websites (supposedly because they're extra sensitive)

Any insight from someone with some network skills?

**[EDIT]**

It turns out it was due to my ISP filtering content from Akamai as explained here : http://help.unotelly.com/support/articles/178800-for-uae-customers-with-du . Thanks @Barmar

Comment: Apple makes heavy use of the Akamai CDN for their download servers. Akamai tries to send you to the server expected to have the best network path to you, but that depends on you using a DNS server that's also close to you in network topology. Are you using your ISP's DNS servers or an alternative like Google DNS or Open DNS.

Comment: Intersting. I thought Apple had switched to its own CDN. I actually use Google as I'm not a big fan of my ISP (Etisalat in Abu Dhabi). I'll try switching to their DNS though.

Comment: I suppose it's possible. I haven't worked for Akamai for 3 years and haven't done any traffic analysis when using App Store.

Comment: www.apple.com is an alias for e3191.dscc.akamaiedge.net.

Comment: I've just found this: http://help.unotelly.com/support/articles/178800-for-uae-customers-with-du  "The filtering is affecting content delivery networks, so basically anyone that hosts videos, images, and other media content are getting filtered so that only lookups done via the ISP DNS servers return anything for the affected CDN. When using third party DNS servers, including Google, many websites are stripped of their media content, along with long delays and eventual timeouts." **Fantastic**

Comment: Yep, works now. I'll learn to love DNS filtering. @Barmar: I'll happily accept your answer if you turn your comment into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your ISP DNS servers instead of a public DNS service like Google Public DNS or OpenDNS. This works better with DNS-based CDN routing, as they can direct your traffic to the closest content server.